# Why travis doesn't set correct JDK?

Tags: java, maven, travis-ci

I'm trying to set up travis build with JDK13, using for it two ways
- by setting `jdk` parameter to `openjdkea` 
- by downloading jdk and setting env variables (installation tested locally),

And still `java --version` is 1.8 and it is used in runtime, even maven uses jdk13 for build.

Here is my `travis.yml`:

```
language: "perl"

perl:
  - "5.14"     
  - "5.26"  

git:
  depth: false    

sudo: false

jdk:
  - openjdk-ea

addons:
  apt:
    packages:
    - python3
    - maven
    - graphviz

before_install:        
    - wget https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk13/21/GPL/openjdk-13-ea+21_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
    - tar xvzf openjdk-13-ea+21_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
    - export JAVA_HOME=$PWD/jdk-13
    - export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
    - ls $JAVA_HOME
    - java -version
    - javac -version
    - mvn -version
    - mysql --version
    - sqlite3 --version
    - env
    - cd wrappers/java
    - mvn clean
    - mvn package
    - cd ../..


install:
    - cpanm -v --installdeps --with-recommends --notest .
    - cpanm -n Devel::Cover::Report::Coveralls
    - cpanm -n Devel::Cover::Report::Codecov

script: "./scripts/dev/travis_run_tests.sh"
```

And here in output you can see java --version is 1.8 that causes test fail, even maven uses jdk13-ea for build.

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
travis_time:end:23204870:start=1558602135904104138,finish=1558602136218922843,duration=314818705
[0Ktravis_fold:end:before_install.18
[0Ktravis_fold:start:before_install.19
[0Ktravis_time:start:16b0d9da
[0K$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_151
travis_time:end:16b0d9da:start=1558602136223048229,finish=1558602136845508635,duration=622460406
[0Ktravis_fold:end:before_install.19
[0Ktravis_fold:start:before_install.20
[0Ktravis_time:start:346a8d88
[0K$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 13-ea, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /home/travis/build/Ensembl/jdk-13
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
```

What am I doing wrong, how to correctly set new JDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution:
Java/bin for PATH variable should be prepended like this:

```
- export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of manually installing java versions, have you tried using [`jenv`](https://github.com/jenv/jenv#11-installing-jenv)?